# How to display a sql blob image in Flutter?

Tags: mysql, flutter, flutter-image

I am currently developing an application for which I need to display images that are stored as BLOB in a MySQL database.

My API returns me the blob image like this :

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,8,3,0,0,0,107,172,88,84,0,0,2,247,80,76,84,69,255,255,255,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,19,246,233,164,0,0,0,252,116,82,78,83,0,136,40,2,240,8,64,48,24,10,215,254,158,1,6,3,4,252,251,253,250,241,5,120,194,12,249,195,224,121,239,190,11,228,86,58,246,183,216,123,244,26,14,15,247,204,226,7,201,234,68,126,227,13,236,31,173,178,238,34,124,55,160,28,140,57,54,161,149,193,188,189,127,165,23,44,156,180,32,230,184,75,106,206,235,53,132,43,248,108,186,245,29,207,38,35,97,221,148,182,200,19,101,131,213,198,187,80,91,50,98,219,52,122,30,74,27,56,100,71,191,84,17,214,211,202,37,243,233,77,110,41,144,146,229,199,20,66,79,162,93,142,174,154,102,185,155,46,16,45,92,129,78,225,175,113,114,210,118,222,94,36,49,117,203,73,95,111,70,33,133,109,65,72,25,62,105,168,18,47,138,88,177,163,139,166,167,159,67,60,137,89,164,103,179,128,39,115,99,170,237,212,242,223,147,205,172,76,135,196,9,83,145,85,181,82,209,63,104,21,220,192,61,119,218,208,217,171,22,69,231,176,59,151,81,169,42,87,134,153,51,232,150,197,141,130,107,96,152,125,112,157,38,168,50,16,0,0,11,63,73,68,65,84,120,94,228,220,249,115,85,229,29,6,240,71,47,56,196,219,187,228,102,1,98,136,36,4,8,144,132,192,16,33,9,4,12,91,19,246,69,89,247,69,118,89,151,1,4,100,83,144,213,202,186,200,166,44,130,32,98,45,86,5,1,169,108,45,224,2,221,180,181,218,90,171,221,59,211,246,135,231,135,206,48,133,78,56,223,247,220,115,111,206,205,61,231,237,231,63,56,51,239,188,207,57,231,251,188,47,28,197,211,109,203,206,241,157,94,31,156,183,167,6,147,139,243,23,46,234,242,206,140,249,111,36,224,255,194,166,121,91,7,167,80,226,205,92,255,100,45,104,237,228,147,221,39,120,105,198,155,183,181,204,7,61,5,102,125,153,70,43,158,46,189,217,12,218,89,126,166,23,173,11,125,214,215,15,141,20,158,27,203,72,165,207,13,66,19,169,71,251,51,26,163,14,6,160,131,111,62,103,180,26,189,231,129,219,149,61,196,170,184,60,223,7,55,123,229,109,47,171,232,55,207,193,181,124,181,147,105,131,53,9,112,167,85,99,104,143,23,23,195,141,78,183,162,93,82,126,234,198,229,31,162,141,58,4,245,95,254,230,234,28,135,155,236,207,164,221,190,250,57,220,227,175,197,180,95,226,75,112,139,199,50,24,19,29,224,14,237,106,48,70,126,4,55,120,52,133,86,165,236,201,235,210,57,239,193,252,52,90,227,157,2,231,251,250,10,195,203,174,115,102,242,253,191,188,27,109,129,146,99,203,94,207,96,120,201,135,225,116,115,150,48,140,196,134,203,166,167,194,40,248,64,135,70,12,103,201,116,56,91,69,47,154,107,84,123,54,212,246,237,236,154,72,83,45,246,193,201,2,93,105,38,185,123,3,132,179,248,84,18,205,140,170,128,131,61,78,51,223,142,128,21,203,191,245,210,68,191,66,56,214,1,47,213,58,151,193,170,205,59,104,226,121,15,28,106,230,37,42,125,190,13,145,152,90,135,106,39,224,76,254,2,42,157,173,139,200,4,238,243,82,37,163,2,142,180,130,42,217,115,17,185,109,25,84,57,5,231,240,207,44,91,186,113,198,63,167,204,106,208,39,137,10,95,188,128,104,148,244,163,202,3,136,191,186,147,223,250,225,195,11,139,25,222,249,186,136,78,205,238,84,120,208,143,248,26,113,104,112,26,45,250,129,31,81,219,232,165,172,30,226,39,248,170,240,202,26,155,231,7,118,81,150,221,19,113,50,188,52,133,172,182,231,7,58,80,118,30,113,81,82,154,200,136,20,249,81,53,190,114,202,38,163,250,205,220,16,98,100,46,39,160,170,82,39,81,148,222,28,213,172,73,167,52,70,232,202,5,84,93,161,34,13,111,162,90,141,91,145,203,136,101,193,14,181,158,161,164,33,170,211,215,153,140,220,10,216,99,62,37,73,237,81,125,118,133,24,185,151,83,97,147,134,148,52,70,117,105,218,134,81,240,206,129,93,74,114,41,248,212,135,234,241,194,52,70,227,44,236,211,150,146,106,154,21,253,43,155,209,24,210,30,246,241,55,162,160,35,170,65,240,59,140,206,251,176,211,106,10,134,52,69,204,249,214,48,58,153,9,176,213,14,10,54,34,230,222,98,148,182,192,94,7,40,24,27,251,248,99,148,22,249,96,175,64,38,5,127,68,108,77,241,50,74,167,97,183,35,20,156,67,76,205,75,102,148,190,132,237,70,120,105,52,26,177,244,88,14,195,73,158,240,240,219,43,106,143,92,154,181,113,247,153,30,189,120,71,90,9,236,247,25,141,234,32,134,22,183,160,185,22,165,243,43,231,80,197,177,122,23,167,121,73,190,133,24,216,75,163,12,196,142,167,128,102,242,143,60,234,129,164,240,244,209,191,52,67,12,36,164,208,168,168,237,97,15,98,99,16,77,180,138,71,157,191,136,162,237,109,143,35,6,154,164,80,233,153,65,205,17,7,71,168,16,186,214,210,7,187,181,161,74,218,238,154,136,139,55,169,54,237,165,85,176,213,82,170,108,47,67,156,116,163,153,129,111,183,134,125,234,230,83,97,204,73,196,75,106,26,77,229,236,12,192,46,235,40,75,106,236,67,252,188,200,48,242,246,195,30,251,19,41,10,45,69,60,149,51,156,196,14,9,176,195,45,138,188,107,17,87,181,25,222,213,99,168,186,161,73,206,44,106,246,161,21,229,245,81,85,239,83,244,125,196,217,80,90,50,113,1,170,198,35,71,64,71,196,93,6,45,185,60,59,22,43,45,61,1,113,215,153,214,164,15,71,85,252,158,146,235,136,191,31,211,162,22,211,17,189,38,98,6,174,135,3,60,65,171,150,180,180,121,8,177,164,61,28,160,29,45,75,203,66,148,60,87,41,216,9,39,168,159,67,203,146,250,32,58,175,81,208,43,8,71,8,12,216,251,201,135,57,180,228,82,107,68,38,216,238,227,163,55,74,7,111,167,224,113,56,72,96,192,193,209,5,3,25,86,65,42,172,43,204,42,207,160,82,82,79,56,77,234,212,115,221,159,166,185,79,96,209,236,19,189,211,104,166,33,28,41,245,230,36,47,205,124,12,11,124,127,154,232,101,24,223,192,169,74,110,124,69,181,148,17,8,171,101,63,10,132,45,208,169,154,143,79,166,82,191,154,48,247,70,111,90,240,14,28,109,192,68,42,109,128,153,153,29,147,104,197,50,56,155,167,111,10,85,166,67,201,243,221,92,90,243,43,56,93,251,159,81,161,7,84,10,139,104,145,183,41,28,111,211,67,84,40,131,236,149,167,104,213,52,184,192,71,69,145,69,248,107,253,105,217,69,184,65,176,148,178,57,16,204,77,166,117,245,224,10,190,239,81,244,60,12,130,43,25,137,99,112,7,255,203,20,53,192,189,70,51,34,191,133,75,244,44,166,100,18,238,241,11,70,36,19,174,113,221,75,73,59,84,242,106,136,17,41,130,123,252,217,194,255,252,17,143,68,92,249,116,143,192,48,10,38,84,106,126,79,96,132,182,193,69,182,81,210,19,119,121,110,49,82,237,225,38,121,20,244,197,93,141,25,206,146,70,93,119,76,76,31,200,59,90,192,85,250,80,112,11,119,28,207,161,137,80,215,101,221,238,20,188,198,109,158,55,114,198,232,245,99,243,207,195,93,10,104,148,253,17,254,235,223,84,235,178,101,1,52,48,139,130,89,184,13,23,66,84,25,118,24,122,240,72,41,215,41,92,245,43,127,173,15,186,56,75,163,237,184,109,14,21,38,45,128,62,222,84,71,89,103,202,86,6,161,145,5,137,52,154,106,210,253,75,126,2,122,233,172,218,5,123,83,52,18,154,217,77,163,15,0,20,166,81,178,14,186,57,64,163,182,0,178,40,233,29,128,110,166,42,114,176,156,130,86,155,160,157,38,114,193,37,152,33,111,0,250,9,122,105,240,44,240,46,5,79,121,160,161,254,52,184,10,172,164,160,15,116,36,140,60,114,225,203,167,209,63,160,165,137,52,194,114,10,78,64,75,163,104,240,8,90,210,200,59,27,90,202,22,54,59,241,212,93,1,180,212,140,70,131,241,107,113,230,165,165,251,197,166,247,10,113,102,164,165,213,52,186,15,23,105,212,26,90,154,66,163,67,144,10,4,126,104,105,43,141,178,240,169,20,13,122,250,137,216,242,201,149,162,65,75,67,41,216,7,241,3,65,75,131,40,72,128,208,171,77,135,150,38,209,104,20,48,140,6,3,161,163,102,201,114,109,122,12,141,198,233,25,130,130,213,64,119,26,117,131,126,60,82,101,178,56,8,140,23,195,81,63,107,41,88,3,160,47,141,202,161,157,230,233,170,115,3,147,105,84,195,15,221,236,162,32,183,190,234,196,217,60,237,34,224,18,5,61,148,233,176,1,154,89,71,201,92,229,189,156,217,179,161,149,44,74,146,42,132,122,164,150,75,96,106,54,37,93,112,91,19,47,141,18,47,64,31,181,90,209,180,40,186,136,130,107,26,37,224,179,20,93,51,111,200,29,132,38,60,167,40,10,13,55,191,135,104,224,163,208,66,211,30,148,253,161,210,188,64,240,183,161,208,192,190,133,148,229,212,194,93,55,40,26,182,10,174,247,110,49,21,198,227,127,78,102,80,180,167,27,92,238,104,136,10,253,155,90,185,136,232,202,117,184,89,131,15,169,116,168,242,209,178,76,202,146,218,250,225,86,195,219,80,237,11,63,42,249,128,42,123,222,243,193,141,42,254,30,162,90,206,102,84,22,152,64,165,188,150,112,155,113,123,219,12,161,9,239,100,220,235,57,154,104,53,250,119,169,112,141,255,144,115,239,172,9,67,81,28,192,131,88,176,20,45,65,138,197,136,216,7,134,210,8,157,76,16,17,186,27,204,160,182,133,34,130,152,209,199,36,40,74,151,70,240,209,197,77,112,178,160,131,155,93,10,130,147,159,193,89,208,193,221,49,67,191,192,53,175,102,240,158,251,223,239,240,187,227,225,156,127,107,117,77,171,218,169,34,0,140,246,19,167,184,143,151,106,3,199,9,231,101,209,243,125,10,237,27,85,55,191,200,127,139,169,164,164,137,46,79,216,209,132,248,149,7,10,157,9,25,254,251,227,205,9,73,18,252,180,198,200,223,195,192,247,7,53,15,128,182,1,232,254,176,78,159,224,60,13,219,47,233,150,187,243,27,200,254,190,129,11,128,208,23,88,190,223,216,2,188,59,11,212,255,97,120,247,111,201,65,244,11,38,6,124,25,5,28,159,49,55,225,173,31,94,65,241,27,29,202,108,248,174,23,12,63,37,91,58,255,26,20,96,240,175,88,203,189,207,179,39,236,245,23,237,113,241,95,83,213,159,50,198,122,78,148,93,54,116,18,178,17,44,245,209,196,58,100,219,138,237,219,240,91,161,241,161,143,164,191,246,238,30,180,169,48,138,227,240,169,73,211,220,146,126,218,36,198,84,154,90,98,173,75,176,41,22,17,145,210,218,58,117,80,27,169,82,63,139,110,130,130,82,17,65,44,130,173,58,180,248,49,233,224,23,84,4,113,112,16,119,167,118,112,118,112,116,113,117,80,207,32,92,138,215,55,127,106,11,183,136,247,156,243,76,239,250,255,141,185,188,111,82,149,68,19,173,179,166,158,177,217,131,223,106,254,107,149,27,87,186,70,75,20,25,198,24,99,140,49,166,255,109,247,251,7,164,215,180,255,49,98,106,3,41,53,218,9,255,24,175,203,71,120,183,70,151,218,54,94,54,66,42,221,15,174,47,100,72,163,58,254,173,214,2,168,80,82,29,96,235,124,125,235,155,39,107,8,144,41,47,93,109,31,238,17,122,125,117,119,110,181,0,201,9,63,201,245,25,18,229,235,49,246,113,62,247,247,0,201,122,246,113,203,30,146,164,131,217,41,0,1,156,253,190,243,36,201,36,59,5,32,0,238,231,65,177,175,186,110,202,97,0,220,207,147,36,73,145,157,2,16,0,247,243,89,146,164,151,161,128,19,0,247,247,53,146,40,55,161,128,19,0,246,243,7,146,37,150,114,11,20,220,0,176,63,75,36,189,128,27,0,247,203,47,240,103,0,220,175,160,192,64,112,238,135,253,26,10,44,5,199,109,240,170,165,232,2,8,246,171,42,128,251,117,21,192,253,186,10,224,126,93,5,112,191,234,2,23,72,160,230,129,132,235,213,25,94,193,124,162,202,37,143,162,110,108,113,39,135,208,50,119,47,226,251,55,114,72,143,146,20,97,177,103,28,218,169,102,138,174,203,188,14,22,4,188,104,29,202,12,69,215,11,14,65,194,239,227,175,57,188,237,251,40,186,10,121,14,45,75,81,230,21,57,164,137,70,138,180,76,37,191,43,94,37,189,194,197,188,214,116,188,74,223,98,87,3,73,1,223,63,209,148,71,64,246,126,44,160,109,63,22,208,182,31,11,232,218,143,58,60,109,251,177,128,182,253,88,64,201,254,161,224,56,8,5,20,236,255,94,23,156,189,20,20,16,191,191,236,124,29,142,65,1,249,251,157,0,4,5,228,239,119,3,84,23,24,145,86,96,24,246,187,1,160,192,59,18,101,47,238,119,3,96,129,89,146,228,11,7,248,0,97,0,44,112,154,36,73,187,251,49,0,22,152,39,73,138,238,126,12,128,5,110,147,36,89,119,63,6,192,2,79,73,146,35,113,103,63,6,128,2,115,49,18,229,196,33,255,138,228,56,173,18,128,98,159,253,175,169,157,183,72,152,82,249,238,203,238,133,181,220,25,242,126,28,61,215,91,176,91,99,210,89,0,11,112,49,120,244,180,137,52,193,139,68,215,72,167,113,94,246,152,116,250,212,206,190,33,210,202,171,105,99,110,249,217,64,122,77,63,63,158,161,127,194,24,99,140,49,198,24,99,140,49,198,24,243,11,180,91,36,124,89,254,71,132,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,174,66,96,130]}
```

I would like to display this image in my Flutter application.

My research on the internet led me to a ByteBuffer component but I can't get it to work. I searched several ways on Google, copied my error codes, searched on YouTube but couldn't find how to do it.

Is it possible ? If so, could someone help me to display this image correctly in my application ?
If not, how to display it then (i don't want to store my image in an accessible link from the web, and I'm using an API) ?

Comment: Try `Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(json['data']))`

Comment: @TirthPatel It worked, thanks ! I just added to your code a cast because if I didn't it would've been throwing an error because of a 'dynamic' type.
`Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(blob['data'].cast<int>()))`
Now I just have to see why my page is lagging but it is another problem. This one solved, thanks a lot ! :D

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I could help. Try running the app in profile mode and see profiler data.

Comment: @TirthPatel Yesss, i'll do this. Thanks !!